# Random Effects in Non-Linear Logistic Growth Model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, nonlinear-functions, random-effects

I am estimating alpha and lambda for each participant at each time point from the following code. Therefore, I need to add two random effects. How do I do this in R?

Both betas are fixed.

`
b0 = 1
b1 = 5

logistic_growth_model <- nls(stage ~ b0 + (b1 - b0) / (1 + exp(-alpha * (age - lambda))),
data = df,
start = list(alpha = 0.9, lambda = 13.5))

summary(logistic_growth_model)
`

I think I can use "gnls" or "nlme" to do what I need to do but I'm having trouble with the syntax to add random effects and keep both betas fixed.

Comment: Something like `nlme(stage ~ b0 + (b1 - b0) / (1 + exp(-alpha * (age - lambda))), data = df, start = list(alpha = 0.9, lambda = 13.5), fixed = alpha + lambda ~ 1, random = alpha + lambda ~ 1, groups = ~ groupID)`? Or maybe `random = pdDiag(alpha + lambda ~ 1)`? Provide data if you need further help.